# Draw on top of a "View"?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which each Activity has a View which shows a PNG Image, followed by a TextView, an EditText and other views... The Activity's Content View is inflated using an XML layout file.

Depending on which options the user chooses/how he interacts with the application, I want to dynamically draw onto the PNG Image.

Is this possible? If so, how? If not, how else could I go about it? Could you point me towards a tutorial on this sort of thing?

Many thanks
Darius

Comment: It's impossible to understand what you wrote :(

Comment: It almost certainly is possible....but you haven't given anything like enough information for people to help you.